# How to check array is null or empty or it contains elements in perl language

Tags: xml, perl

I am parsing the following XML and taking the ip addresses from the XML data. While accessing  $region -> { 'IpRange' } it is throwing error as Not an ARRAY reference at ExtractXmlIps.pl line 45. Some times Region does not contain any values. In that case I am getting this error. When I added the check like "if( $region && $region -> { 'IpRange' })" it is still throwing error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<IpAddresses xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Region Name="us" />
<Region Name="asia">
    <IpRange Subnet="10.10.10.0/21" />
</Region>
</IpAddresses>
```

Code to parse the xml:

```
getstore ( $urls[0], $file_path );
my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $xml_data = $xml -> XMLin ( $file_path );
foreach my $region ( @{ $xml_data -> { 'Region' } } ) {
    foreach my $ip ( @{ $region -> { 'IpRange' } } ) {
        print $ip;
    }
}
```

I add null check for region and inside the region. Tried to find the length of the array and added that check also.

Comment: Can you show what you are doing. more of relevant code? We don't know what "_ExtractXmlIps.pl_" is like, nor how you "_parse the xml_", nor what "_error_" it's throwing, nor what your "_null check_" is.

Comment: Follwong is the XML:                                                                                         
 <IpAddresses>
<Region Name="us" />
<Region Name="asia">
 <IpRange Subnet="10.10.10.0/21" />
</Region>
</IpAddresses>                                                                                                          In the above xml in first loop I am taking region in second loop I am taking ips. Some of the regions doesnot contain value hence @{ $region -> { 'IpRange' } } is throwing error.

Comment: @KarthikS, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56489347/edit) to add the missing code and error text. We need to be able to run the code in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: XML::Simple? Um... is this some old existing program? From the first line of [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple): *PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS MODULE IN NEW CODE.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of not reading the documentation. Use [strict mode](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple#STRICT-MODE).

```
use 5.010;
use XML::Simple qw(:strict);
my $xs = XML::Simple->new(ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => []);
my $root = $xs->XMLin('so-56489347.xml');
foreach my $region (@{$root->{Region}}) {
    foreach my $iprange (@{$region->{IpRange}}) {
        say $iprange->{Subnet};
    }
}
```

The documentation also says to use [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) instead.

```
use 5.010;
use XML::LibXML qw();
my $root = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'so-56489347.xml')->documentElement;
foreach my $region ($root->getChildrenByTagName('Region')) {
    foreach my $iprange ($region->getChildrenByTagName('IpRange')) {
        say $iprange->getAttribute('Subnet');
    }
}
```

But when you have that library, you can simply use XPath to find your desired XML elements, much shorter!

```
use 5.010;
use XML::LibXML qw();
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'so-56489347.xml');
for my $iprange ($doc->findnodes('//Region/IpRange[@Subnet]')) {
    say $iprange->getAttribute('Subnet');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the documentation for XML::Simple, when there is only one child element it is returned as `name => 'value'`, instead of `name => [ 'value' ]` which is what your code expects. You can change

```
$xml_data = $xml -> XMLin ( $file_path );
```

to

```
$xml_data = $xml -> XMLin ( $file_path, ForceArray => 1 );
```

so that all child elements are returned as array refs.